# Buttons in dialog boxes sticking to the bottom

Tags: android

I'm building a custom dialog box for my Application. While doing so, my OK and Cancel buttons are going right to the bottom of this view i.e. to the bottom edges of the dialog box. How can I pull these up a little so that there is a slight gap between the buttons and the bottom edge of the dialog box. 
My XML code is as follows:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/settingsview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Select Settings" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/onemin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/settingsview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/settingsview"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/radio_one" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/twomin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/onemin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/onemin"
    android:text="@string/radio_two" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/tenmins"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/twomin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/twomin"
    android:text="@string/radio_three" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/set"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/onemin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tenmins"
    android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_livid_brown"
    android:text="@string/submit_btn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/set"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/set"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/twomin"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_livid_brown"
    android:text="@string/cancel" />
```

Comment: have you tried `padding`?

Comment: Is you parent view's height set to wrap_content? You may try either use bottom margin or explicitly set dialog's height (this variant is not good unless you have dimensions for different screen or dynamical height setting).

Comment: hi, padding is moving the text inside the button and not the actual button

Comment: Wrap your buttons inside a layout (ex. LinearLayout) and set `padding` to the layout

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using gravities? this is my solution when i have trouble with positioning my widgets.

basically, you need some parent "container" where your buttons are in and then position them with changing the gravities within the container for your widgets.

Vogella has a good tutorial for this topic!!

[vogella-tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/)

Answer (score 0):

Though you don't provide your full code here.Not sure whether you use above things in a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.But as you say..

> How can I pull these up a little so that there is a slight gap between
>   the buttons and the bottom edge of the dialog box

So i think `android:layout_marginTop=""` can do the trick,if you decrease those values.
Use

`android:layout_marginTop="10dp" //change this value according to you need`

And if you want to move you buttons a little bit left rather than right then change..

```
android:layout_marginRight="30dp" //change this value according to you need
```

I show here 2 examples of how can you improve those condition.If you still face problem then post full **xml** code here so that i can test that in my environment.